# Disabled dropdown has a blue background

Tags: google-chrome

I am facing an issue in chrome 16.0.912 browser. My Disabled dropdown has a blue background. How can I remove blue background ? Is there any jquery or any css property ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bugg in Chrome, see this URL:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89509

It happens because you have a background-image set to something or a background-color set to transparent. Two ways to "fix" this problem on the fly through css would be:

```
select:disabled
{
    background-image: none;
}
```

or

```
select:disabled
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

I really don't think there's a way for jQuery to address this problem.

Comment: Thanks Andreson I had already set that issue on that day through background image. That Project already completed..

Comment: we can resolve this only in one way to use in a background method. Like a using by Plugins method. Best Example is Uniform.